# Why does zabbix not see the Update Interval in my Item?

Tags: zabbix

I am on Zabbix 3.2.3 on RHEL 7.x
The update interval for my Item is 1800s i.e., 30 minutes.
When the Item is enabled it runs and executes a bash script which I created as an external check every 10 minutes and not every 30 mins (which I had configured in the Item's update interval field). I am not able to understand why this is happening. I dont have any custom intervals for this Item.
The bash script runs fine from the zabbix host in the bash shell in external scripts folder and also can be invoked from the zabbix web UI successfuly.

Since the item is listed with an "unsupported" status, could [this](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/administration/general?&#other_parameters) be the reason ?

BTW I have tested the end-to-end scenario successfully on my local docker with zabbix 3.2.11 and 3.4.0 and everything works perfectly.

Can someone please help me troubleshoot this ?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

the reason why it is executed is, that the status is unsupported.

When a item is not working correctly, it trys every 10 minutes to retrieve a new value to see if it's working again. (Or what you have defined as unsupported retry value)

You have to check why it's returning unsupported, most of the time you can just hover over the "unsupported" text and it shows you what is causing the problem.

When the script works fine from the commandline, but not from the agent, you have either a permission/user problem, or the returned value is not a valid value.

Setting the debug log level in the agent to 3 or 4 helps find the problem

Comment: Thanks that helped. I just simplified the code and also removed a sleep statement.